# OpenVPN routing windows to access lan on client side of windows

Tags: openvpn

I have multiple OpenVPN servers for each customer running on PFSense so they have their own network for there devices. The PFSense firewall is running on Vultr server instance. I have HMI/SCADA software running on windows panel type PCs acting as a web server. I use a reverse proxy to point DNS down the VPN tunnel to access the web server, this works well and has no issues.

If I connect to one of these OpenVPN servers from my Laptop to access the PLC on the LAN I can't get to the lan behind the windows 10 panel PC. I have tried:

1. turning off the windows firewall and followed a lot of guides,
2. have IP forwarding enabled on windows and still no luck.

Out of interest, I tried it on a raspberry pi and I was able to access everything on the LAN, so it is something windows is stopping but I can't figure it out and have spent weeks trying to get it to work. I have tried adding all the remote networks in the OpenVpn config etc. with no luck.

Is there some settings I am missing in PFSense or OpenVPN?

My [image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzqOM.jpg

Thanks

Comment: imgur image doesn't load.

Comment: You need to give more information such as PLC brand and type. The PLC might active block connection if you're not accessing the right database from the start. Portforwarding as you describe this is merely a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: Here is the new link https://imgur.com/gallery/UHLEJTm

Comment: The PLC I am using is Siemens S7-1200 and have tried Allen Bradley micro820. I can ping them fine from the panel PC I just can't ping them via OpenVPN connection. I put other devices onto the Network and can't ping them either. I don't think port forwarding is an option since I don't have access to the router onsite or It's just a 4G LTE module in the Panel PC providing the internet connection. I have tried static routes in windows but don't understand how they work correctly so I feel they are wrong or whether a static route can route to the LAN

Comment: Start looking at SNAP7 for python. Also check some of my questions/answer about the S7-1200. This will give you direct access to the PLC and skip OpenVPN, etc. I'm pretty sure we get this tackled in a week. The panel PC you're talking about is an Siemens HMI? Or regular touch screen PC (e.g. LC touch).

Comment: The Panel PC is Advantech and running windows 10 iot enterprise ltsb. So basically full windows but without windows store and all that kind of stuff. I am running Indusoft SCADA as a web server and I can access the web server fine and view remotely. Is there any type of router software I can run that will allow routing to the LAN from the OpenVPN Tunnel?

Comment: Just looked at SNAP7 and that's for reading/writing variables to and from the PLC. I just need to access the LAN so I can upload/download to the PLC from Tia Portal that is Installed on my Laptop.

Comment: With SNAP7 you can check whether you have direct access or not. If you then use wireshark you can see in much more detail where it gets blocked. Its been a while I used Indusoft SCADA. Which version are you running? I can try next week to setup and try to simulate your issue using your settings if not solved by then.

Comment: I will have a look with Wireshark. But I feel it's just a routing issue with windows since I can't access any device on the LAN. All the devices on the LAN are set with static IP and is an unmanaged network if that makes any difference? I don't think anything is blocked since I can ping from CMD on the panel PC itself